# mySQL query to find the most repeated value

Tags: mysql

I have a table with several rows, for each of them I need to know the most common value.

Example:

row_1 has

```
car
boat
car
car
truck
truck
plane
car
car
```

as its values.

I need to know what is the most common value (in this case car).
I have several ideas, but since I must do this for the 30 rows I would like an easy and not CPU intensive query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find most frequent value in SQL column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235595/find-most-frequent-value-in-sql-column)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To get a list of values and the number of their appearances:

```
select col_name, count(col_name) c from table
group by col_name
order by c desc;
```

If you want only the most common value:

```
select col_name, count(col_name) c from table
group by col_name
order by c desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 4):

I wrote the query in a way such that if there are more items with the same highest number of occurrences, you will see them all, not just one of them.

```
select item
from table
group by item
having count(item) = (
select count(item) as great
from table
group by item order by great desc limit 1)
```