# Select most common value from a field in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a million rows, how do i select the most common(the value which appears most in the table) value from a field?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mySQL query to find the most repeated value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581609/mysql-query-to-find-the-most-repeated-value)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You need to group by the interesting column and for each value, select the value itself and the number of rows in which it appears.

Then it's a matter of sorting (to put the most common value first) and limiting the results to only one row.

In query form:

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS magnitude 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY magnitude DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 28):

[This thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/getting-the-most-frequent-value-from-mysql-table-45795/) should shed some light on your issue.

Basically, use `COUNT()` with a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT foo, COUNT(foo) AS fooCount 
FROM table
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY fooCount DESC
```

And to get only the first result (most common), add

```
LIMIT 1
```

To the end of your query.

Comment: This should be `ORDER BY fooCount DESC`

Answer (score 7):

In case you don't need to return the frequency of the most common value, you could use:

```
SELECT foo
FROM table
GROUP BY foo
ORDER BY COUNT(foo) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

This has the additional benefit of only returning one column and therefore working in subqueries.