# Custom MODE() function usable like MIN() or AVG() in MySQL

Tags: mysql

Just like `MIN()` and `AVG()` i sometimes need the most common occuring value (AKA the mode) of an integer value. This can be obtained as such:

```
SELECT column, COUNT(*) AS x 
FROM table 
GROUP BY column 
ORDER BY x DESC
LIMIT 1
```

And thats quite a mouthful. I'd really like to use it like: `MODE()`

```
SELECT AVG(`sTemperature`), MODE(`sSwitch`), MODE(`sDoor`)
FROM `stats`;
```

Is there a way to make the above query work for Integers?
For Booleans, i figure `ROUND(AVG())` is fine.

Its possible to define functions in a MySQL DB, but can they work on datasets as MIN() or AVG() does?

Because i use it a lot inside things like:

```
INSERT INTO `statsaggregates` (
  `saMeasurements`, `saTemperature`, `saSwitch`, `saDoor`
) SELECT 
  COUNT(*)            as 'saMeasurements',
  AVG(`sTemperature`) as 'saTemperatureAvg',
  MIN(`sTemperature`) as 'saTemperatureMin',
  MAX(`sTemperature`) as 'saTemperatureMax',
  MODE(`sSwitch`)     as 'saSwitch',
  MODE(`sDoor`)       as 'saDoor'
FROM `stats`
WHERE 1
```

Note: There are other SO questions like [Select most common value from a field in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql) that ask how to calculate mode. This question is about using it exactly like AVG() in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately, you can not do that with MySQL UDF "normal" definition possibility. The only way to do this is to define such thing [in C/C++ but not SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/adding-udf.html):

> For the UDF mechanism to work, functions must be written in C or C++
>   and your operating system must support dynamic loading. MySQL source
>   distributions include a file sql/udf_example.c that defines five UDF
>   functions. Consult this file to see how UDF calling conventions work.
>   The include/mysql_com.h header file defines UDF-related symbols and
>   data structures, although you need not include this header file
>   directly; it is included by mysql.h.