# Use distinct with top 10

Tags: mysql, distinct

I want to select the users from a database called log_buyers. log_buyers is a log with all items i sold to users. I use DISTINCT on field USERID to collect only the buyers one time (some people buy more items). I use it like this:

```
$lsel_log = mysql_query("select DISTINCT userid from log_buyers order by id");
while ($log = mysql_fetch_array($lsel_log)) {
```

Now i want to have the 10 most common users and see how much each user in the top paid. 
In the same table (log_buyers).

```
  $lsel_log = mysql_query("select DISTINCT userid from log_buyers order by id");
  while ($log = mysql_fetch_array($lsel_log)) {  

$lsel_total_5 = mysql_query("select * from log_buyers where userid = '$log[userid]' order by id desc");
 $total = mysql_num_rows($lsel_total_5);
 $total = $total * 5; 
echo "$log[userid] - $total";
```

The code works fine, except he is doing it for all the users who bought. I only want to do it for the top 10 users. (Most common in log_buyers).

Comment: @BernardoLima `TOP` doesn't work in MySQL, that's SQL Server or Oracle.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Select most common value from a field in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Using `GROUP BY` with `COUNT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) should get you the most common `userid`s in that table.

```
SELECT userid FROM log_buyers 
GROUP BY userid 
ORDER BY COUNT(userid) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

in the first query, add `LIMIT 10` at the end of the query

Comment: That don't give me the most common 10 users in log_buyers

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy question you should add LIMIT 10 to your query.

Edit: I think you will find your answer [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql)

Comment: That don't give me the most common 10 users in log_buyers

Comment: so maybe you need this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql

Comment: @Banzouzi I just updated my answer... I edited at the same time as your comment Robert, sorry for that