# Get the most common value in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the fields **animal** and **number** like this:

```
    Horse   1
    Mouse   2
    Cat     2
    Horse   4
    Cat     2
    Mouse   1
    Horse   1
    Horse   3
    Mouse   2
    Cat     1
```

Now i want to get the most common value for each animal.
So i expect this result:

```
Horse   1
Mouse   2
Cat     2
```

Is it possible to do this with one mySQL query?
I have no idea how i could do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select most common value from a field in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693613/select-most-common-value-from-a-field-in-mysql)

Comment: The duplicate reference only returns one row (LIMIT 1). This question is not the same.

Comment: What is your Mysql version? and how you want handle ties?

Comment: @ThomasG - `1` is the most common `number` for "Horse".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a sub query to get that:

```
SELECT c.animal,MAX(c.cnt)
FROM (
  SELECT t.animal, t.number, count(*) AS cnt
  FROM your_table t
  GROUP BY t.animal, t.number) c
GROUP BY c.animal
```

Comment: `MAX(c.cnt)` is not the *most common* `number`.

Comment: misunderstood the question, sorry

Comment: Never mind. OP seems not to care much about correct results.

Answer (score 2):

For versions pre 8.0:

```
select distinct a.animal, (
  select b.number
  from animals b
  where b.animal = a.animal
  group by b.animal, b.number
  order by count(*) desc
  limit 1
) as number
from animals a;
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/8YHdSVAvUTNGRxaBRkKfHw/0)

With MySQL 8.0 (or MariaDB 10.2):

```
with count_all as (
  select animal, number, count(*) as cnt
  from animals
  group by animal, number
), count_max as (
  select animal, max(cnt) as cnt
  from count_all
  group by animal
)
select animal, number
from count_all
natural join count_max
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hwfBtp5qjS2U7Bdx4fjBgg/0)

Note: If there are ties - The first query will return only one row per animal. The second will return them all (tied rows). You didn't specify what to do in such case.

As pointed out by Juan Carlos Oropeza - In MySQL 8 you can also use window functions `ROW_NUMBER()` or `RANK()`

```
with count_all as (
  select animal, number, count(*) as cnt
  from animals
  group by animal, number
), count_max as (
  select animal, number,
    row_number() over (partition by animal order by cnt desc) as rn
  from count_all
)
select animal, number
from count_max
where rn = 1
```

This will not return ties. If you want to get tied rows, just replace `row_number()` with `rank()`.

Comment: With mysql 8 you can use row_number or rank.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I first thought it's to much code :-) - But after your comment, I realized, that it's more flexible.