# relational model query for simple person-car example

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

I'd like some insight on a relational model I have created for PostgreSQL. It has to do with person and car relationships.

```
CREATE TABLE "person" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"name" varchar(300) NOT NULL,
"car_id" integer REFERENCES car (id));

CREATE TABLE "car" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"type" varchar(50) NOT NULL);

 CREATE TABLE "car_person_relations" (
"id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
"car_type" varchar(50) NOT NULL REFERENCES "car" ("type"),
"person_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "person" ("id"));
```

Ultimately, I'd like to get the **most popular car type** based on how many people have it,
i.e. how many "person"s it is associated with. What query can I use to achieve this? And is this relational table (`car_person_relations`) sufficient to achieve it?

Any insight would be much appreciated

Comment: Please show what you've tried. What parts can you do? But this is a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Thanks Phill. And I apologize if my question didn't well-align with StackOverflow's "How to Ask" policy. Frankly I am completely new to databases, and I just had no idea where to start or look, but I will surely keep that in mind for future questions. @philipxy

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL query to find the most repeated value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581609/mysql-query-to-find-the-most-repeated-value)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this is a simple aggregation with some limiting:

```
select car_type, count(*) as num_persons
from car_person_relations cpr
group by car_type
order by count(*) desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

First off take a look at your data model, it has a couple fundamental problems.
In CAR_PERSONS_RELATIONS table you are attempting to create a FK on car_type. However, to do so car_type would have to be
unique in the car table. From the documentation section [5.4.5. Foreign Keys](http://5.4.5.%20Foreign%20Keys) .

> A foreign key constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values
>   appearing in some row of another  table. We say this maintains the
>   referential integrity between two  related tables. ...   A foreign key
>   must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique
>   constraint.

But this would there could only be 1 car for a given type in the
table. 
  
Now look at the PERSON table. This table contains a FK to car_id, thus establishing a M:1 to CAR. Basically this relationship 
says "A person can own only 1 car, but a car can be owned by many persons". Your description and table name indicate 
this is NOT the relationship you are trying to define.

Correcting requires the following changes:

1. Add car_id to CAR_PERSON_RELATIONS.
2. Remove car_id from PERSON.
3. Remove car_type from CAR_PERSON_RELATIONS.
4. Redefine CAR_PERSON_RELATIONS PK to car_id, person_id.  
      Alternately
   leave the surrogate PK and create UK on car_id,person_id).
5. Create the FKs from CAR_PERSON_RELATIONS to CAR and PERSON.

**Revised Model**

```
create table person (
   id   serial       
  ,name varchar(300) not null
  ,constraint person_pk primary key (id) 
);

create table car (
   id serial  
  ,type varchar(50) not null
  ,constraint car_pk primary key (id)  
  );

create table car_person_relations (
   car_id    integer   
  ,person_id integer 
  ,constraint car_person_relations primary key (car_id, person_id)
  ,constraint car_person_relations_2_car_fk
              foreign key (car_id) 
              references  (car.id)
  ,constraint car_person_relations_2_person_fk
              foreign key (person_id) 
              references  (person.id)
):
```

And then the necessary query becomes:

```
select cpr.car_type, count(*) as num_persons
  from car_person_relations cpr
  join car                  c
    on cpr.car_id = c.id 
 group by cpr.car_type
 order by count(*) desc
 limit 1;
```